# Reads int. file(txt) from command line and make even odd files

Tags: c

wrote this code don't know why its not working

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

int main (int argc, char *argv[]){

    int i=1;
    //this is where i started loop read file.      
    for (i=1; i<argc;i++){

        FILE *file1 = fopen("argv[i]","r");//reading file

        FILE *file2 = fopen("even.txt","w");//making even file

        FILE *file3 = fopen("odd.txt","w");//odd file
        //These are the files i am reading and writing to.
        int nums;

Main looping 
       while (file1  != EOF)
       {

           fscanf (file1,"%d",&nums);

           nums++;
           //adding the conditions to what i want each file to have.

           if (num % 2 == '0'){
               fprintf (file2,"%d",nums);
            }

            //if condition fails move the numbers to the Odd file.
            else {
                fprintf (file3,"%d",nums);
            } 

        //I tried the loops here but ut gave me segment error.
        }
    //closing all files

    fclose (file1);
    fclose (file2);
    fclose (file3);
    }
return 0;
}
```

Comment: `fopen("argv[i]", "r")` tries to open a file named exactly `argv[i]`. You want to do `fopen(argv[i], "r")` instead without the quotes.

Comment: A `FILE *` can not be compared with `EOF`

Comment: The condition `file1 != EOF` should never be false. If `fopen` fails it returns `NULL` and `EOF` is equal to `-1`.

Comment: and `num % 2 == 0`, rather than `'0'` because it will be the number 1 or 0, not the ascii character `0`

Comment: int main (int argc, char *argv[]){
        int i=0;
        for (i=1;i<argc;i++){
        FILE *fp1 = fopen (argv[i],"r");
        FILE *fp2 = fopen ("evens.txt","w");
        FILE *fp3 = fopen ("odd.txt","w");

int num;
while (!feof(fp1)) {
        fscanf (fp1,"%d",&num);
        if (num % 2 == '0'){
        fprintf (fp2,"%d",num);}
        else {
        fprintf (fp3,"%d",num);
        }
        }
//while (!feof(*fp1));
fclose (fp1);
fclose (fp2);
fclose (fp3);
}
return 0;
}

I did make some change

Comment: still having that error

Comment: Please post the [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) which shows what you have tried. I can only see disjointed driblets in the post and in comment. I see the dreaded and usually incorrect `while !feof(...)`. I see you using `argv` without checking `argc`. I see you opening files but not checking they did open. I see `fscanf` used without checking its result. Etc. This is riddled with basic errors, check your progress and many of your problems will be evident.

Comment: It's just a mess.  I can't be bothered to look at messes.  Next....

Answer (score 0):

Modify the following line to compare with an `integer.`

```
if (num % 2 == '0') // This is wrong, you are comparing `int` with `character`
 {
   fprintf (file2,"%d",nums);
 }
```

Change it to;

```
if (num % 2 == 0) // This is wrong, you are comparing `int` with `character`
{
   fprintf (file2,"%d",nums);
}
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: It did help Thank You so much! Brother.

Comment: Please verify the answer by accepting it, so that it help to others.

Comment: Data1 = 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 10
In even File - 2 4 6 8 10
In odd File - 1 3 5 7 9